# Console log is full of tcp errors mostly from Safari, all coming from google domains

Tags: network, safari, dns, google

My console log the past week has been full of these errors. Generally they appear when anything accesses a google domain using HTTPS, such as loading fonts, or google analytics, or even google css files from their CDNs. How do I figure out what can do this? My ISP is brighthouse/charter. Until recently this didn't happen. I have switched DNS providers, cleaned the DNS cache, no extensions other than 1password, restarted, removed history, tried Chrome (same problems). No idea what to do now.

```
7/31/16 9:58:58.643 PM Safari[746]: tcp_connection_tls_session_error_callback_imp 224     __tcp_connection_tls_session_callback_write_block_invoke.434 error 32
7/31/16 9:59:52.353 PM Safari[746]: tcp_connection_tls_session_error_callback_imp 231     __tcp_connection_tls_session_callback_write_block_invoke.434 error 22
7/31/16 10:00:28.955 PM Safari[746]: tcp_connection_tls_session_error_callback_imp 240     __tcp_connection_tls_session_callback_write_block_invoke.434 error 22
7/31/16 10:00:56.088 PM Safari[746]: tcp_connection_destination_handle_tls_close_notify 239 closing socket due to TLS     CLOSE_NOTIFY alert
7/31/16 10:00:56.088 PM Safari[746]: tcp_connection_tls_session_error_callback_imp 239     __tcp_connection_tls_session_callback_write_block_invoke.434 error 32
7/31/16 10:00:56.090 PM Safari[746]: tcp_connection_destination_handle_tls_close_notify 238 closing socket due to TLS     CLOSE_NOTIFY alert
7/31/16 10:00:56.093 PM Safari[746]: tcp_connection_destination_handle_tls_close_notify 236 closing socket due to TLS     CLOSE_NOTIFY alert
7/31/16 10:00:56.093 PM Safari[746]: tcp_connection_tls_session_error_callback_imp 236     __tcp_connection_tls_session_callback_write_block_invoke.434 error 32
7/31/16 10:00:56.098 PM Safari[746]: tcp_connection_destination_handle_tls_close_notify 235 closing socket due to TLS     CLOSE_NOTIFY alert
7/31/16 10:00:56.098 PM Safari[746]: tcp_connection_tls_session_error_callback_imp 235     __tcp_connection_tls_session_callback_write_block_invoke.434 error 32
7/31/16 10:00:56.100 PM Safari[746]: tcp_connection_destination_handle_tls_close_notify 237 closing socket due to TLS     CLOSE_NOTIFY alert
7/31/16 10:00:58.632 PM Safari[746]: tcp_connection_destination_handle_tls_close_notify 234 closing socket due to TLS     CLOSE_NOTIFY alert
7/31/16 10:00:58.632 PM Safari[746]: tcp_connection_tls_session_error_callback_imp 234     __tcp_connection_tls_session_callback_write_block_invoke.434 error 32
```

Comment: Are you looking to find the beta version of Safari to see if it's a new bug in Google's recent change to HSTS ? https://security.googleblog.com/2016/07/bringing-hsts-to-wwwgooglecom.html or is this more a concern about CPU or resource usage on logging 100k messages a day? If it's just debugging the connection, we can get into `nsurlsessiond` [debug](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205249/how-to-know-what-nsurlsessiond-is-downloading) or just the web inspector.

Comment: I guess I could try the beta to see if does something different. It happens on both my Macs at home but not at work. In network tab it's always coming from google, its always HTTPS but not every connection which is odd. Chrome has the same behavior.

Comment: HSTS only affects the main google domain, all of these "hung" requests came from other google or google owned domains.

Comment: Safari developer preview has exactly the same issue