# Dump dom of url from command line with safari?

Tags: safari, command-line, development

The following command will dump the dom for a web page using Google Chrome:

```sh
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome  --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom http://example.com
```

I'm wondering if something similar is possible for Safari.

I can do this with AppleScript but I'd prefer the solution for Safari to be "headless" (see `--headless` option in command above), so I think an AppleScript will not achieve what I'm looking for.

** UPDATE **

Selenium driver has a headless mode for other browsers. But it doesn't look like there is such a mode for safari: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58314435

Answer (score 1):

I’m fairly confident Safari isn’t amenable to scraping, so use Chrome or Firefox for that on macOS if you need a browser to be scriptable.

However, swift and [python](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/) are exceptionally good at this by calling code directly via [NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl) or equivalent as well as using the NSURLSessiond daemon and working with the OS directly and not even needing Safari.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517065/web-scraping-in-apple-swift-3
- [How to know what nsurlsessiond is downloading](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205249/how-to-know-what-nsurlsessiond-is-downloading)

Of course you have to learn some new language and API/SDK for this to pay off. The pay off can be huge if you have a command line tool that does all the heavy lifting far more efficiently than Chrome or Safari can.