# For macOS 10.14+, where are in-progress downloads for software updates stored?

Tags: macos, software-update

I am downloading a macOS Monterey Beta using the Software Update "application" in System preferences, a feature since macOS 10.14. Out of curiosity, and for users whose downloads are interrupted by a power outage, internet loss, kernel panic, etc.; when the download is in progress, where are these installer file(s) stored?

I have found other [questions](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/where-does-mac-os-mojave-save-the-catalina-update-file-not-in-library-updates.2245985/) and answers point to `/Library/Updates`, however this directory is `10MB>` when I download an update. [Others](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653270) point to `/private/var/zz`. One thing that I am sure of is that the file(s) is/are stored client-side, as I slowly watch my hard drive space go down with the download.

This is in contrast to the previous update system (pre-Mojave) where you download the installer from the App Store, and it would stay in `/Applications/` all the time.

In short: for macOS 10.14+ users, where is the location of in-progress downloads started by `Software Update`?

Comment: 1. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space 2. Check file system activity 3. check the files open by the software update process

Comment: How do you want me to check file system activity? Option 1 points me to paid software and (from my understanding) shows the biggest files on the drive

Comment: `fs_usage` https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205249/how-to-know-what-nsurlsessiond-is-downloading/205257#205257 // you just looked at the first answer.. there are free apps there which show breakdown of the entire disk.

Comment: ok, so I tried some apps and they all had to index my drive. The update finishes downloading before the app finishes indexing. `fs_usage` returns `/dev/disk1s1`, but I don't know how to access it. `diskutil list` says the Volume name for `disk1s1` is `Macintosh HD`.

Comment: you can pause the software download process by issuing a STOP signal. And then do the indexing.