# How to know what `nsurlsessiond` is downloading

Tags: internet, monterey, daemons

I have nsurlsessiond downloading at about 1.5 MB per second for a full day now, making other internet activities on my laptop less responsive. I tried killing the nsurlsessiond but it just comes back after a few minutes. Based on [How to know what nsurlsessiond is downloading](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205249/how-to-know-what-nsurlsessiond-is-downloading)

I already ran the command `brctl log -w` and it gave the following output:

```
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.010+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┏  asking container ID for <private>, com.apple.dt.Xcode
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.010+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┗  end
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.018+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┏  asking container ID for <private>, com.apple.iWork.Keynote
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.018+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┗  end
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.022+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┏  asking container ID for <private>, com.apple.iWork.Pages
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.022+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┗  end
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.026+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┏  asking container ID for <private>, com.apple.iWork.Numbers
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.026+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┗  end
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.031+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┏  asking container ID for <private>, <private>
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.031+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┗  end
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.114+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┏  asking container ID for <private>, com.apple.iWork.Pages
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.114+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┗  end
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.123+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┏  asking container ID for <private>, com.apple.iWork.Keynote
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.123+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┗  end
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.137+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┏  asking container ID for <private>, <private>
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.137+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┗  end
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.145+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┏  asking container ID for <private>, com.apple.iWork.Numbers
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.145+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┗  end
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.152+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┏  asking container ID for <private>, com.apple.dt.Xcode
[dbg  2022-01-21 14:50:05.152+0100] nsurlsessiond[35911]  ┗  end
```

I confirmed in activity monitor that 35911 is indeed the PID of the process that is doing all the downloading so I feel like I am close to the source of the downloading.

However I have no idea what this output means and how to determine whether all this downloading that is going on is something useful, or just something unnecessary that I can disable somehow.

This is on OS X 12.1 fwiw.

Update: Xcode, Keynote, Numbers and Pages that can be seen above were all updated yesterday. But the downloading is still continuing after all these updates happened. And the app store is also not showing any new pending updates.

Comment: Have you tried running a netstat -an on your machine and seeing what IP it's connecting to?